# Use Cucumber to test Java console output?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I've only ever used Cucumber in conjunction with Selenium to test websites.

I'm now trying to write a feature file to test a class but I'm not sure how, I have my test step running which calls the main method passing in some arguments. The main method does some things with the arguments and prints them to the console. Is it possible to read the console output to a string so I can assert it matches what I expect?

```
   @Given("I pass the arguments {string} to the generator")
   public void i_pass_the_arguments(String string) {
       String[] args = string.split(" ");
       new Generate();
       Generate.main(args);
   }
```

Comment: I think in this case it would be more appropriate to start a new process with the [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)/`ProcessBuilder`. You can easily redirect the standard output of the new process using this facility.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes and no. Just run JUnit tests for this. You don't need the overhead. That said, Cucumber is just a shell for your test cases. You can create Cucumber scripts mapped to methods that invoke console commands, etc. Selenium is what makes it not possible. Why? Selenium is a library that was created **_specifically_** to test web applications via web browsers. It is not design to test desktop applications, OS features, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing a specific class only, I'd recommend using unit tests for that, for example using JUnit. They will have less overhead and be easier to run and maintain.